# writing pattern in xsd for <a attributes><img/></a>

Tags: xsd, pattern-matching, xsd-validation

I am trying to apply pattern for an element in xsd.

Element is of type XHTML.

I want to apply pattern like this.

```
<a attributes="some set of attributes"><img attributes="some set of attribtes"/></a>
```

Rules:

```
    <a> tag with attributes followed by <img> with attributes.
```

Sample Valid Data:

```
  <a xlink:href="some link" title="Image" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <img  alt="No Image" title="No Image" xlink:href="soem path for image" xlink:title="Image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
  </a>
```

Invalid:

```
    <a>data<img/></a>--Data Present, no attributes
    <a><img>abcd</img></a>--data Present, No attributes
    <a><img/></a>---No attributes
```

Can any one suggest how to write pattern for this.

```
        <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Need help"/>             
        </xsd:restriction>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not generating an xsd from the a valid XML and then use it to validate the other xmls?

Answer (score 1):

The XSD `pattern` facet is used to constrain the 'lexical space' of a simple type (that is, the set of literal strings that denote instances of the type) using regular expressions.  It won't help you to require that certain elements must have attributes.

If you want specific attributes to be present (e.g. `title` and `xlink:href` on the `a` element, `title` and `alt` on the `img` element), the simplest way to do so in a schema is by declaring those attributes as required.  The schema for XHTML 1.0 strict, for example (at http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#xhtml1-strict) declares both `src` and `alt` as being required on `img`:

```
<xs:element name="img">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="attrs"/>
    <xs:attribute name="src" use="required" type="URI"/>
    <xs:attribute name="alt" use="required" type="Text"/>
    ...
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If what you want is just to require that *some* attributes be used, but you don't care which, XSD doesn't make the task easy: in XSD 1.0 there is no convenient way to say "I don't care which attribute appears, but there has to be one".  You *can* enforce such a constraint (even if some observers like me find it a bit odd) by using assertions in XSD 1.1, or by using a Schematron schema in addition to your XSD schema.